# Generating set for $\sigma(\mathcal{G}, X)$ where $\mathcal{G}$ is sub sigma field and X is a r.v.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm trying to prove the following fact.

Let $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-field and let $X : (\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{P})
\rightarrow (S,\mathcal{S})$ be a random variable. Then
\begin{align*}
  \sigma(\{ A \cap \{ X \in B \} : A \in \mathcal{G}, B \in \mathcal{S} \}) = \sigma(\mathcal{G}, X)
\end{align*}

Here's what I have so far:

Let $P = \{ A \cap \{ X \in B \} : A \in \mathcal{G}, B \in \mathcal{S} \}$. Clearly $P \subset
\sigma(\mathcal{G}, X)$ by definition.  Furthermore, $\sigma(\mathcal{G},X)$ is a $\lambda$-class
since it is a $\sigma$-field.  To show $P$ is a $\pi$-class, just note that 
for $A_i \in \mathcal{G}$ and $B_i \in \mathcal{S}$,
\begin{align*}
  A_1 \cap \{ X \in B_1 \} \bigcap A_2 \cap \{ X \in B_2 \} = (A_1 \cap A_2) \cap \{ X \in (B_1 \cap B_2) \}
\end{align*}
and we have $(A_1 \cap A_2) \in \mathcal{G}$ and $(B_1 \cap B_2) \in \mathcal{S}$.
By the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem,
we have $\sigma(P) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{G}, X)$.

I'm not quite show how to show $\sigma(P) \supset \sigma(\mathcal{G}, X)$. I don't think $Q \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \mathcal{G} \cup \sigma(X)$ is a $\pi$-class (it does not seem closed under intersection). And it also doesn't seem that $P \supset Q$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if $G\in\mathcal G$, then 
$G=G\cap \{X\in S\}$, which belongs to $\mathcal P$, that is, $\mathcal G\subset\mathcal P$.

In a similar way, $\sigma(X)\subset\mathcal P$. We thus have $\mathcal G\cup \sigma(X)\subset\mathcal P$, hence $\sigma(\mathcal G\cup\sigma(X))\subset\sigma(\mathcal P)$.

Comment: I'm not seeing why $\sigma(X) \subset P$. $\sigma(X) = \sigma(\{ \{X \in B\} : B \in \mathcal{S} \})$ right? So I certainly believe that $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(P)$, but how do you know $P$ contains all the generated sets necessary to complete the $\sigma$-field?

Comment: Take $A:=\Omega$: we have $A\cap \{X\in B\}=\{X\in B\}$ and the LHS is an element of $\mathcal P$.

Comment: Thanks Davide. I was being dumb and forgetting that $\sigma(\{ \{X \in B \} : B \in \mathcal{S} \}) = \{ \{X \in B \} : B \in \mathcal{S} \}$ because $\mathcal{S}$ itself is a $\sigma$-field. Now it is clear.